# Safari won't Zoom In with Command +

Tags: safari, shortcut, keybindings, zoom

⌘+ no longer zooms in Safari content for me.  ⌘- works just fine for zooming out.  Selecting View -> Zoom In menu item does work as expected.

I have also tried using an administrator account that has little to no additional software installed, but get the same results.

Running macOS 10.12.2 on 17" Early 2011 MBP

Comment: Does Cmd/shift/+ work?

Comment: @Tetsujin it does! I suppose it makes sense because on the MBP keyboard, the unshifted key is equals and the same shifted key is plus.  The weird thing is that on another MBP, the unshifted combination works as it should.

Comment: Both actually should work - that only the shifted version does work implies something else has 'stolen' it & at least gives somewhere to start looking.